# how active record sample works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I happened to see a line

```
Item.where(conditions).limit(10).order('created_at desc')
```

And I wonder it is similar to

```
Item.where(conditions).order('created_at desc').limit(10)
```

Seems ok as per new changes to rails 3, active record

But how about if we want, sample 10 items, *ordered by created_at*. This was my question #1

question 2 is 'limit' works within query, 'sample' does not..right?, it seems to be taken care of ruby array sample..right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you check the railscast [episodes 239 active relation walkthrough](http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough) to understand how it works.

Basically, the internal work is done by [Arel gem](https://github.com/rails/arel), activerecord object simply maintains the arel object when you do chaining. By the end of the day, it lets `arel` generate the sql statement, then it calls the `find_by_sql` with the generated sql statement.

The thing is that whether you called `order` before `limit` or the other way round, the generated sql statement is simply the same. Everything is executed by the database backend, activerecord simply parse the results and build up objects back.